# How to get newest TypeScript code highlighting in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2015

Class names are not highlighted in blue in VS 2013 update 4 (with latest [TypeScript 1.4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2F2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304&ei=JP4rVfqZB9D8oQSArYDYCQ&usg=AFQjCNFoikJBcO6_X9bCwp20Ec3Rkuhldg&sig2=YQZmIAAY_dwuuqvBALhXuQ) installed):
[image: TypeScript classes are not highlighted in blue in VS 2013]

in VS 2015 Preview they are highlighted:

[image: TypeScript classes are highlighted in blue in VS 2015 Preview]

Is there a way to get same nice C#-looking formatting in VS 2013?

Answer (score 1):

No. CTP5 is what is the *supported by install* way forward at the moment.

There are hacks (to use a custom version of LS) : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2656#issuecomment-90858643